# XCode Linking build error

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode

This one is new to me. Not even sure what RootViewController.o is? though this project does have a **.m** & **.h**. Building for Simulator 3.0. Cleaned before build (Shift-⌘-K).

Recently added some classes from another project that also had a RootViewController...but I didn't transfer old one over. Haven't built since. This could be part of the problem?!?

**Building target “MyApp” of project “MyApp” with configuration “Debug” — (1 error)**

```
    cd "/Volumes/MacHD/Development/iPhone/MyApp"
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.5
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk -L/Volumes/MacHD/Development/iPhone/MyApp/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Volumes/MacHD/Development/iPhone/MyApp/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Volumes/MacHD/Development/iPhone/MyApp/build/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/MyApp.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -o /Volumes/MacHD/Development/iPhone/MyApp/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp
Undefined symbols:
  ".objc_class_name_MyViewController", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@MyViewController in RootViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Build failed (1 error)

---

**Edit:** Cleaned ALL targets... still won't build. Here's my #includes:

**RootViewController.h**:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyViewController.h" //tried with this and as @class MyViewController

@class AddViewController, EditingViewController;

@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    MyViewController *myVC;
    UINavigationController *navController;
    AddViewController *addViewController;
    NSArray *keys;
    NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter;
}
```

**RootViewController.m:**

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "MyAppDelegate.h"
#import "MyViewController.h"
#import "AddViewController.h" 
#import "EditingViewController.h"
#import "MyObject.h"
#import "ViewCell.h"
#import "AppColors.h"
#import "CustomCellBackgroundView.h"

// Manage the editing view controller from this class so it can be easily accessed from both the detail and add controllers.
static EditingViewController *__editingViewController = nil;

@implementation RootViewController
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RootViewController.m has a reference in it somewhere to MyViewController, but you haven't linked in a file with an `@implementation MyViewController` in it. RootViewController.o is the object file created by compiling RootViewController.m.

Comment: Hi Rob, Thanks again for your help.  I #import MyViewController.h (MVC) from within RootViewController.m.  (RVC) and I've tried @class MVC and #import MVC.h from within RVC.h.  What does this "symbol(s) not found" mean? what "symbol" is the compiler talking about?

Comment: Meltemi: You're talking about preprocessing, which is completely separate from linking. `#import` has nothing to do with linking. You need to make sure MyViewController.m is added to your target.

Answer (score 1):

Try to clean all targets before building.  If this doesn't work, post the code for RootViewController.h and .m, especially the #includes.  The .o extension refers to the object file created by your compiler.

Answer (score 1):

There is also another thing to do: check in the file list when you select the "Classes" group. The checkbox next to the **.m** files must be enabled (which tells XCode to compile and link the file) especially if u add them with "Add existing files..." command.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. The answer is in the comments on one of the answers:
Select the "classes" group and make sure all your .m files checkboxes are checked in the "Target" column